# Problem installing g++

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, g++

I typed

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

then got the output:

```
g++ depends on g++-4.8 (>=4.8.2-5~) but it will not be installed
```

Then I continued

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
```

then got

```
g++-4.8 depends on: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 will be installed
gcc-4.8 (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 will be installed
libstdc++-4.8-dev (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it will not be installed
```

Then I typed

```
sudo apt-get install  gcc-4.8-base gcc-4.8 libstdc++-4.8-dev
```

then got

```
gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 will be installed
libgcc-4.8-dev (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 will be installed
```

Finally

```
sudo apt-get install libgcc-4.8-dev gcc-4.8-base
```

and got

```
libgcc-4.8-dev is the newest version
gcc-4.8-base is the newest version
```

So, should I remove thoese installed packages and substitute by version in parenthesis ? Do anyone know the way to fix ? Any help would be much appreciated !

For anyone suggests installing build-essential: Here is what i got

```
build-essential: depends on g++ (>= 4:4.4.3) but it will not be installed
```

Comment: g++ is installed by default in 14.04, im sure, open terminal and run `g++` and it should say `g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.` Indicating it is installed

Comment: Did you remember to run `sudo apt-get update` before you started? it looks like the package indexes are not quite in sync

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have a similar problem: g++ --version says it's 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04, but apt-get thinks it has 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 installed even after apt-get update...